# SwiftUI Custom SF Symbol appears blurry in macOS TabBar / settings window

Tags: macos, swiftui, tabbar, sf-symbols

I am trying to use a custom SF Symbol as image within a `.tabItem` but it appears blurry:

[image: Screenshot of a blurry custom SF Symbol]

```
TabView(selection: $selectedTabItem) {
    // ...
    SomeView()
        .tabItem {
            Label(title: {
                Text(verbatim: title)
            }, icon: {
                Image("custom.symbol.name")
            })
        }
        .tag(1)
}
```

`SF Symbol.app` successfully validated the `svg` file I am using with no complains and it looks good in Xcode’s AssetCatalog as well.

The icon also looks just great if I’m using it in other places.

Is this a SwiftUI bug or am I doing something wrong? Is there a way to workaround/fix that?

Comment: Can you post some code where you are using this?

Comment: Sure. Just added a code snippet @yawnobleix